# Calling a JavaScript function from another view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, dom-events

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and was wondering where JS functions for the views go. I have a table element in a view that displays the @RenderBody part of _Layout, and in it's th elements, I have -

```
<th id="one" oncontextmenu = "return menu(this)">label one</th>
```

Where should the function main(..) be located? Can it be in the script tag on the _Layout page or are individual view pages allowed to have their own script tags where this should go?

I've worked in WebForms before, so moving to MVC, I'm having trouble visualizing how to put all the pieces together. Help please!

Comment: it is better to include all scrips in master page.and then u can access it everywhere you want.

Comment: I've tried placing the function in both places, it is as simple as function menu(elem) { alert(elem.id); }, but it isn't getting invoked, hence i thought i was doing something wrong.

Comment: are u familiar with developer tools like firebug?

Comment: how you included your script?have you defined inline or it is in external file?if is possible show your script code.

Comment: inline. In _Layout and in the Index.cshtml of the respective controller, i have script tags with the function definition

Comment: go to page source with your browser and check to see if you'r script rendered correctly.

Comment: I'm using the4 chrome debugger. I've put a breakpoint in the menu function, which is never reached. So, it is not getting called at all.

Comment: try calling function from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you defined your script in your layout page u can use it anywhere else.there is no limitation in calling javascrip function cross-view.

Answer (score 1):

- It can be in the Same view file surrounded by a script tag
- It can be in the Layout.cshtml file surrounded by  script tag
- It can be in a external javascript file referred in the same view
- It can be in a external javascript file referred in the
  `Layout.cshtml` view

`Layout.cshtml` works similar to Master page. so whatever you include there will available to all the views which uses the layout.